# Overriding image issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, image

Here is my issue:
I'm trying to loop through folder get the files from the folder and save each file to an image and then to the DataBase but for some reason the length of the image is the same all the time. like it's not creating a new instance of an image.

Here is my code + comments:

```
   Dim dba As New DBAccess
        Dim folderName As String = String.Empty
        Dim imageFileName As String = String.Empty
        Dim ms1 As New MemoryStream()
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet


        If m_IncidentCaseID > 0 Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sessions.GetKeyValueSessionFile(m_SessionID, "IRPicturesPath")) Then
                m_IncidentPicturesPath = Convert.ToString(Sessions.GetKeyValueSessionFile(m_SessionID, "IRPicturesPath"))
            End If

            folderName = m_IncidentPicturesPath '!= Set the path of the folder.

            '!= For Each file get the data from the DataBase: PictureID,PictureIndex,PictureFileName.
            m_HashTableIRPicturesWriter = New Hashtable
            m_DictionaryEntryIRPicturesWriter = New DictionaryEntry
            Dim strArr As String() = Directory.GetFiles(folderName)

            For Each filePath As String In strArr
                ds = dba.GetPicturesIDFromPath(filePath, m_User.CompanyCode)
                If Not ds Is Nothing Then
                    m_HashTableIRPicturesWriter.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("PictureID").ToString(), filePath)
                End If
            Next


    '!= We saved each file Path +PictrureID to Hashtable
    '!== Loop through the hashtable and for each file in the folder create an image.        

            For Each filename As DictionaryEntry In m_HashTableIRPicturesWriter
                Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename.Value())
                Dim bytes As Byte()
                img.Save(ms1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                bytes = ms1.ToArray()


                '!=================================== Delete and Insert to the Temp_Table in the DB ==============================!
                Dim dBConnection As String
                dBConnection = Globals.GetConnectionStringMain(m_User.CompanyCode())
                Dim connString As New SqlConnection(dBConnection)

                '# First Delete the table from the IncidentID that we want to insert.
                Dim sql1 As String = "Delete From Temp_Incident_Images Where PictureID =" & filename.Key()
                Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand(sql1, connString)
                If connString.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    connString.Open()
                End If
                cmd1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@IncidentID", m_IncidentCaseID))
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                connString.Close()

                If connString.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    connString.Open()
                End If

                '# Second Inserst the PictureID to the Table.
                Dim sql As String = "Insert Into Temp_Incident_Images(PictureID,IncidentID,IncidentImage) values (@PictureID,@IncidentID,@IncidentImage)"
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, connString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncidentID", m_IncidentCaseID)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PictureID", filename.Key())


                Dim data As Byte() = ms1.GetBuffer() '!=When checking the Data it's same all the time.
                Dim p As New SqlParameter("@IncidentImage", SqlDbType.Image)
                p.Value = data
                cmd.Parameters.Add(p)
                Try
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw New SystemException(ex.Message.ToString.Trim)
                End Try
                ms1.Close()
                connString.Close()
                img.Dispose()
            Next
        End If
```

[image]

How can I create a new instance of an image from this lines of code:

```
Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename.Value())
                    Dim bytes As Byte()
                    img.Save(ms1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                    bytes = ms1.ToArray()
```

Comment: What's the point in reading the data into an `Image` and then saving that to a `Stream` to get a `Byte` array?  Why not just call `File.ReadAllBytes` to get a `Byte` array directly from the file?

Answer (score 0):

if you having image path issues with database here is simple code you can work with.

add file upload and a label or anything like this,

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
```

after that add a button which performs the any operation you want.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-info pull-right" id="UploadButton" text="Upload" onclick="UploadButton_Click" />
```

inside the button add

```
Try
                If FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType = "image/jpeg" Then
                    If FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400 Then
                        Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName)
                        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/") & filename)
                        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!"


                    Else
                        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 100 kb!"
                    End If
                Else
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only JPEG files are accepted!"
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message
            End Try
```

Please let me know if it solves your problem I can edit the code if you need any more help.